# Open XML SDK - Insert Picture in a Sharepoint Document

Tags: c#, image, sharepoint, openxml-sdk

I have that problem using the open xml sdk 2.0 in a Sharepoint solution. My objective is add a image using the net url of the image for the a template document of my user inserted in a list, a attachments in the end of the document to be exact but always the file end corrupted and when recovered, the picture it's not showing.

I will post the codes I'm using:

```
        public static String teste()
    {
        //Url image for test
        string fileName = @"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2a/Junonia_lemonias_DSF_upper_by_Kadavoor.JPG";
        return InsertAPicture(fileName);
    }

public static String InsertAPicture(string fileName)
    {

        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPList list = web.Lists["Documentos Compartilhados"]; //I'm using Portuguese Sharepoint
        SPListItem item = list.GetItemById(5); //For test only
        byte[] byteArray = item.File.OpenBinary();
        using (MemoryStream memStr = new MemoryStream())
        {
            memStr.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);


            using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memStr, true))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

                ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);

                WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
                byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(fileName);

                using (MemoryStream image = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Write(myDataBuffer, 0, myDataBuffer.Length);

                    imagePart.FeedData(image);
                }

                AddImageToBody(doc, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));

                OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
                var errors = validator.Validate(doc);
                Boolean valido = true;
                String s = "";
                foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in errors)
                {
                    s += error.Description + "    ";
                    valido = false;
                } //Just checking for erros, the code it's not returing any

                if (valido)
                {
                    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();

                    string linkFileName = item.File.Item["LinkFilename"] as string;
                    item.File.ParentFolder.Files.Add(linkFileName, memStr, true);

                    return "";
                }
                else {
                    return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }

private static void AddImageToBody(WordprocessingDocument wordDoc, string relationshipId)
    {
        var element =
                    new Drawing(
                        new DW.Inline(
                            new DW.Extent() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L },
                            new DW.EffectExtent()
                            {
                                LeftEdge = 0L,
                                TopEdge = 0L,
                                RightEdge = 0L,
                                BottomEdge = 0L
                            },
                            new DW.DocProperties()
                            {
                                Id = (UInt32Value)1U,
                                Name = "Picture 1"
                            },
                            new DW.NonVisualGraphicFrameDrawingProperties(
                                new A.GraphicFrameLocks() { NoChangeAspect = true }),
                            new A.Graphic(
                                new A.GraphicData(
                                    new PIC.Picture(
                                        new PIC.NonVisualPictureProperties(
                                            new PIC.NonVisualDrawingProperties()
                                            {
                                                Id = (UInt32Value)0U,
                                                Name = "Pic.jpg"
                                            },
                                            new PIC.NonVisualPictureDrawingProperties()),
                                        new PIC.BlipFill(
                                            new A.Blip(
                                                new A.BlipExtensionList(
                                                    new A.BlipExtension()
                                                    {
                                                        Uri =
                                                          "{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}"
                                                    })
                                            )
                                            {
                                                Embed = relationshipId,
                                                CompressionState =
                                                A.BlipCompressionValues.Print
                                            },
                                            new A.Stretch(
                                                new A.FillRectangle())),
                                        new PIC.ShapeProperties(
                                            new A.Transform2D(
                                                new A.Offset() { X = 0L, Y = 0L },
                                                new A.Extents() { Cx = 990000L, Cy = 792000L }),
                                            new A.PresetGeometry(
                                                new A.AdjustValueList()
                                            ) { Preset = A.ShapeTypeValues.Rectangle }))
                                ) { Uri = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" })
                        )
                        {
                            DistanceFromTop = (UInt32Value)0U,
                            DistanceFromBottom = (UInt32Value)0U,
                            DistanceFromLeft = (UInt32Value)0U,
                            DistanceFromRight = (UInt32Value)0U
                        });

        // Append the reference to body, the element should be in a Run.
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.InsertBefore(new Paragraph(new Run(element)), wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.LastChild);
    }
```

Somebody have a ideia of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After you create image stream it's data pointer shows to the end of the stream that leads to feeding no data to the imagePart. Move data pointer to the beginning of the stream

```
using (MemoryStream image = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Write(myDataBuffer, 0, myDataBuffer.Length);
    image.Position = 0;  //<----
    imagePart.FeedData(image);
}
```

Comment: Continue with the same problem. Corrupted file and recovered file with image not showing (instead is showing a x)

Comment: Having the exact same issue.  Any remedies for this?

Answer (score 0):

First, considering that you want to get the image from a document library, you can open the list item file as a stream

```
protected ClientResult<Stream> OpenFileFromListItemAsStream(ClientContext context, string libraryTitle, string filename)
    {
        //source list and list item
        var sourceList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryTitle);
        var sourceListItems = sourceList.GetItems(new CamlQuery
        {
            ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/><Value Type='Text'>" + filename + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></</View>"
        });
        context.Load(sourceListItems);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        ListItem sourceListItem = null;
        if (sourceListItems != null && sourceListItems.Count() > 0)
            sourceListItem = sourceListItems.FirstOrDefault();

        var fileStream = sourceListItem.File.OpenBinaryStream();
        context.Load(sourceListItem);
        context.Load(sourceListItem.File);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        return fileStream;
    }
```

Then you create a memory stream and set position to 0

```
var imageStream = OpenFileFromListItemAsStream(imageContext, imageEntity.LibraryTitle, imageEntity.Filename);
                                    using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
                                    {
                                        imageStream.Value.CopyTo(memStream);
                                        memStream.Position = 0;
                                        imagePart.FeedData(memStream);
                                    }
```

finally...

```
AddImageToBody(doc, mainPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart));
```